# Convert unknown encoding to Hebrew

Tags: php

I am getting the following string from json file:

```
äîé÷åã ùééê ìëúåáú: éùåá:
```

How can I convert it or get the Hebrew characters.

Original text should be:

```
המיקוד שייך לכתובת: ישוב:
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

http://www.online-decoder.com/he says it is:

ISO-8859-1 => ISO-8859-8

Comment: Also note it has English interface at http://www.online-decoder.com/he/ei

Comment: I changed the encoding using `return mb_convert_encoding(utf8_decode($str), "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-8");` now I am getting bunch of ????

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode your json file to UTF-8

You should encode to utf-8 from the beginning. I mean: modify the script that create the json file instead of decoding a bad encoded json output.